# Warning in findings rows: mx_el_eq: automatic broadcasting operation applied

Tags: warnings, octave

I have a matrix, `s`, like this:

```
s =

   1   2   3
   4   5   2
   4   4   2
```

I want to find rows where is 4 in first column and 5 in second, so I create this:

```
sum((s(:,1:2) == [4 5]),2) == 2
```

Which works fine and return:

```
ans =

   0
   1
   0
```

The everything was great, but this part of code: `s(:,1:2) == [4 5]),2)` generate warning:

> warning: mx_el_eq: automatic broadcasting operation applied

What is the proper way to comparision more than one columns? I want to create code without warnings.

Comment: I'm not sure if that warning is really a problem for Octave, I have a feeling it's just pointing out that this is an instance where Octave differs from Matlab and this code would fail in Matlab. In Matlab you have to explicitly request broadcasting using the `bsxfun` function. Octave dies it automatically (like Python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bsxfun with "eq" (equal):

```
s = [1 2 3; 4 5 2; 4 4 2]
all (bsxfun (@eq, s(:,1:2), [4 5]), 2)
ans =

   0
   1
   0
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you get a warning is that automatic broadcasting was a new feature that could catch users by surprise. This warning was meant to be temporary and has since been removed (Octave 4.0.0 was the first release that removed this warning).

It doesn't really mean you're doing something wrong, quite the opposite. If it does the right thing for you, you've found a new quite powerful feature. If you are comfortable using this feature, you can turn off the warning:

```
warning ("off", "Octave:broadcast")
```